# Windows Phone 8 IE 1px horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have a parent div that has a width less then it's child width. What is happening on Windows Phone 8 Phonegap App is that if there is enough content within the div that requires the div to scroll vertically, we are able to scroll 1px across horizontally.

I have tried setting the following attributes to no avail:

```
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

I have a link below simulating the problem I'm facing. This is the user agent string I am currently testing on:

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0 ARM; Touch; HTC; Windows Phone 8S by HTC)

http://jsfiddle.net/7unP5/26/

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with using -ms-scroll-limit
I haven't tried it, but it looks like it might do what you are looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127336(v=vs.85).aspx